# Permutations: Interpreting Image Notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I have a problem in interpreting permutation. I think the definition and my interpretation of it don't match each other.

Let $\sigma=(1\ 2\ 4\ 3)$, and $\tau=(1\ 3\ 2\ 4)$ in one-line notation.

I thought $\sigma$ is a '3, 4 swapping rearrangement of 1 2 3 4'
and $\tau$ is a '2, 3 swapping rearrangement of 1 2 3 4' like swapping data in a computer memory.

The problem is this : I interpreted $\sigma\tau$ as 'first swap 2 and 3, then you get 1 3 2 4, and then swap the elements in the 3rd and 4th place obtaining 1 3 4 2'.

But the definition says $\sigma\tau=(1\ 4\ 2\ 3)$. I thought in reality, the permutation is just a place-changing operation, but by definition, composing two permutation is not just changing place twice. What is wrong in my interpretation?

Comment: Sorry I should have noticed that I'm using a image notation. So $\sigma$(1)=1, $\sigma$(2)=2, $\sigma$(3)=4, and $\sigma$(4)=3.

Comment: What text are you using? Please cite a source and page numbers.

Comment: @anon I'm using W.Keith Nicholson's 'Introduction to abstract algebra 4th edition'. The page number that I referred to is p.55.

Answer (score 2):

When we write $(1243)$, we mean the permutation defined where $1 \mapsto 2$ and $2 \mapsto 4$ and $4 \mapsto 3$ and $3 \mapsto 1$.

Likewise, $(1324)$ means we have $1 \mapsto 3$ and $3 \mapsto 2$ and $2 \mapsto 4$ and $4 \mapsto 1$.  Finally, any number not written inside a set of parentheses with other numbers is presumed to be fixed.  So, for example, if we think of these as permutations in $S_6$, both $\sigma$ and $\tau$ fix $5$ and $6$.  Notice that these are indeed bijective maps!  So the way a layman thinks of the word "permutation" is indeed a correct way of thinking about what's going on.  This notation is called "cycle notation" which kind of makes sense: the permutation can be visualized as equidistant points on a circle, and the circle gets rotated so that each point gets moved to its immediate counterclockwise neighbor.

Now we can compose these with each other.  Doing so, let's see where $1$ is sent.  $\sigma \tau(1) = \sigma ( \tau (1)) = \sigma(3) = 1$.  Looking at $2$ next, we have $\sigma( \tau (2)) = \sigma(4) = 3$.  And so forth.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple levels of confusion, here (and I have deleted my previous answer because of this).

Many posters here are accustomed to cycle notation, where $\sigma = (1\ 2\ 4\ 3)$ means this:

$\sigma(1) = 2\\ \sigma(2) = 4\\ \sigma(3) = 1\\ \sigma(4) = 3.$

It is also possible to employ "image notation" where $\sigma = (1\ 2\ 4\ 3)$ means this:

$\sigma(1) = 1\\ \sigma(2) = 2\\ \sigma(3) = 4\\ \sigma(4) = 3.$

Finally, sometimes $\sigma\tau$ means $\sigma$ first, then $\tau$, and sometimes it means $\tau$ first, then $\sigma$ (as in ordinary function composition).

So it's not immediately clear which conventions your text is using.

A *third* source of confusion is what $(1\ 2\ 4\ 3)$ is instructing us to do: are we swapping the NUMBERS $4$ and $3$, or whatever numbers are in the $3$rd and $4$th positions? This makes the whole situation even murkier.

It appears your text is using "image notation", and "normal composition", so that:

$\sigma\tau(1) = \sigma(\tau(1)) = \sigma(1) = 1$

$\sigma\tau(2) = \sigma(\tau(2)) = \sigma(3) = 4$

$\sigma\tau(3) = \sigma(\tau(3)) = \sigma(2) = 2$

$\sigma\tau(4) = \sigma(\tau(4)) = \sigma(4) = 3$

which is indeed $(1\ 4\ 2\ 3)$ in "image notation".

Comment: Hmm. Something doesn't fit with this interpretation of "one-line notation" as a cycle. You have $\tau(1)=3$ and $\sigma(3)=1$ (which is what the cycle notation would, indeed, tell us). But then $\sigma\tau(1)=\sigma(3)=1$, which does not match the given product. In fact, as product of cycles we have $(1243)(1324)=(1)(234)$.

Comment: Indeed, everything I wrote makes no sense, I am revising it, but the site is giving me trouble.

Comment: My text is using both cycle notation and matrix notation(which you called as image notation)!, and in my question, I used the image notation.

Comment: I agree with the first and the second sources of confusion, but I don't believe there is a the third one. A permutation is just that -- a map from $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$ to itself. By itself it maps numbers to numbers. In order to make it swap the entries of a list, you have to make it act on lists; it's still the same permutation, acting through a group action, not a different permutation.

Comment: In principle, I agree, as long as one is *consistent*. But if you start out swapping numbers, and then start swapping positions instead (that is, switch "2nd" and "3rd" when you mean to switch "2" and "3") there will be trouble.

Comment: I have mostly seen the definition of permutations as _bijections_ (i.e., "it maps 2 to 3, wherever those two happen to be at the moment"). But some times the "switch the number in postion 2 with that in position 3" interpretation makes partial appearances mid way and confuses things. I think it is possible to make sense of both "interpretations", but haven't figured it out completely yet and the confusion persists. There is some sort of psychological/didactic hurdle here the deserves a more through explanation, I think...